# different HTTP verbs from one environment to another

Tags: xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm currently trying to understand why I'm calling twice POST `myendpoint` in production. I'm using `axios` to fetch my API

In development for one call to the API I got one line for OPTIONS, one for POST : 
[image]

in Production for one call to the API I got two POST lines : 
[image]

Is that a normal behavior?